Why does MN 140 refer to not being shaken & not yearning?
I read the following on the internet:

MN140 - "Having gone beyond all conceiving, one is called a sage at
peace. The sage at peace is not reborn, does not grow old, and does
not die. They are not shaken, and do not yearn. For they have nothing
which would cause them to be reborn. Not being reborn, how could they
grow old? Not growing old, how could they die? Not dying, how could
they be shaken? Not shaking, for what could they yearn?" Note that
"they do not die" is only because of rebirth has ended. Best not to
get that confused.

Is the above translation accurate? If a person is already biologically dead, why would they be shaken & yearn? Does the term "Deathless" mean "rebirth" (reincarnation) has ended?

Best not to introduce the word "reincarnation" there. Reincarnation is a Hindu concept where they believe a permanent soul that returns to a new body. So it's best to stick to "rebirth" if you are referring to a Buddha's teaching.

What is rebirth? What is the Pali word for "rebirth"?

If 'reincarnation' is Hindu, why does Sujato use it in his translations? https://suttacentral.net/search?query=reincarnation

"To be biologically dead" is a conceiving. Conceiving to be biologically dead seems to come with raging (kuppati) and yearning (piheti). Why is that? Because of confinement to self interest, hate, and delusion (MN 1).
For dying, one needs to come from somewhere first, one needs a provenance, a background (jāti). One cannot die if having no backgroud.

With the cessation of craving , clinging cease. With cessation of clinging , becoming ceases. With cessation of becoming , rebirth ceases. With cessation of rebirth , ageing, death ceases.
This is deathless. Craving can be called yearning. When there is nothing to loose or gain there is no insecurity and therefore remains unshakable.
This is Nibbana. Nibbana is unborn therefore deathless.

the Pali word "jati" does not mean "rebirth". There is no "re" in jati

“Jati” means group with some common sanskhara. If there was clinging aggregates and after death there is still clinging to aggregates then in that sense there is rebirth. @DhammaDhatu
